# Laravel проблема с url

Tags: php, laravel

Только познаю азы Laravel. Как сделать так, что бы в адресной строке адрес был идентичен файлу, который отвечает за данную страницу.
Работал со стандартным методом аутентификации. Но после проверки совпадает ли данный существующий юзер с паролем, оказываясь на нужной странице, в адресной строке по прежнему находится `auth/login`.
Роуты:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', ['uses' => 'HomeController@dashboard', 'as' => 'dashboard']);
Route::get('auth/login/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login/', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

HomeController:

```
public function dashboard()
    {
        return view('pages.dashboard');
    }
```

AuthController:

```
 protected function postLogin()
    {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $pass = Input::get('password');

        if ($email && $pass)
        {
            $user = AuthModel::where('email', $email)->where('password', $pass)->get();
            if (count($user) == 1)
            {
                return view('pages.dashboard');
            }
         }
    }
```

То есть после успешного логина отображается страница `dashboard`, но в адресной строке находится `auth/login`. Как сделать что бы в адресной строке было `dashboard`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return redirect()->intended('dashboard');`